# How can I add notes to a photoshop document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'd like to **add textual notes to a Photoshop file**, like the notes you can write when preparing a power point, not seen by the end user but only by the presenter.

I need to add quick notes about the layers, instead of having to flesh the whole idea or forget what it was all about. Is this possible?

Comment: Weird suggestions in the answers... There is a note tool in the toolbar. In newer versions it is grouped with color picker.

Comment: @Joonas: you are correct. Thank you (and if you want to add it as the answer, I'll accept it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Photoshop has a `Note tool`, that sits at the top section of the toolbar and is grouped with color picker.

---

Older versions of PS:

- `Note tool` is located at the bottom section of the toolbar. Can't remember what it was grouped with.
- In older versions the note opens up where it is placed and you can keep multiple notes open at once. In the newer versions (cs5+?), they all open up in a single panel when clicked and you can only show the contents of one note at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a suggestion for a single layer but if you would like to write info for a group you can simply create an extra layer, write text in it and make it either invisible or drag it outside the artboard. I use this especially for fonts I use, I type the name of the font in an extra layer and make it invisible.

Another option may be naming the layers and groups well; there is no harm in giving them long names.

Also you may want to use folders for more complex artwork; when you have many layers (and groups) folders are very helpful in organizing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit File info, under file > file info...

but i think i know what you mean and so i would recommend adding folders to group certain layers and naming them well, really well. Usually the layer pannel is small and can only fit a few words but if you like you can expend it how wide you want it to be so you can fit whole sentences.

hope it helps